# How to populate an array of array in Twig?

Tags: arrays, symfony, twig

I have a problem with an array of arrays in Twig.
Here is the code I am struggling with :

```
{% set tabTmp = {0:{},1:{},2:{},3:{},4:{},5:{},6:{},7:{},8:{}} %}
{%for element in box.elements%}
  {% set tab = tabTmp[element.category.id] %}
  {% set elementId = element.id %}
  {% set tab = tab | merge({elementId:element}) %}
{% endfor%}

{%for key, tmp in tabTmp %}
  {% if tmp is iterable %}
     {{ dump(tmp) }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor%}
```

box.elements and element exist, element.category.id and element.id are integer and element is the object I want to work with.

But I keep having Array(0) as a result of dump(tmp).

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything looks fine, but if you want to merge a variable as key to an associative array you need to use `()`; 
so try changing

```
{% set tab = tab | merge({elementId:element}) %}
```

To

```
{% set tab = tab | merge({(elementId):element}) %}
```